# How to return response from cognito async function and display it on the page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, amazon-cognito

Given the code below, how will I output the response back on the webpage when the response is either success or fail?

```
loginUser(data) {
    var authenticationData = {
      Username : data.email,
      Password : data.password
    };
    var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
    var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(config.cognito);
    var userData = {
      Username : data.email,
      Pool : userPool
    };
    var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
    var output = null;
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: function (result) {
          output = result;
          return output;
      },
      onFailure: function(err) {
          console.log(err);
      },
    });
}

<div id="test_mg"></div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use an `async function` and `Promise` in order to get the result from the async call.

```
function loginUser(data) {
    var authenticationData = {};
    var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
    var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(config.cognito);
    var userData = {};
    var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
    var output = null;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: resolve,
        onFailure: reject,
      });
    });    
}

async function main() {
    try {
      var output = await loginUser(data);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ele, your solution works great! I wanted to know is it possible to update the state with the response that I get back to display it on the page?

Comment: actually, never mind. I figured it out. Still, thank you for your help though!