# AWS Cognito returning undefined error async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52408607/how-to-return-response-from-cognito-async-function-and-display-it-on-the-page) as I am attempting to wrap the `authenticateUser` SDK method in a `Promise` and resolve/reject that.

Code:

```
async function cognitoAuth(credentials, next, res) {
    const userData = {
        Username: credentials.email,
        Pool: userPool
    };
    const authenticationDetails = getAuthenticationDetails(credentials);

    let userCredentials;
    let authenticatedUserResponse;

    cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);

    try {
        userCredentials = await checkIfAuthenticated(credentials.email);

        if (userCredentials.UserStatus === CognitoUserStatus.FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD) {
            res
                .status(203)
                .send(userCredentials);
        } else if (userCredentials.UserStatus === CognitoUserStatus.CONFIRMED) {
            authenticatedUserResponse = await authenticateUser(authenticationDetails);

            console.log(authenticatedUserResponse);
        }
    } catch(err) {
        if (err.message === CognitoErrorMessages.USER_NOT_EXIST) {
            next({
                name: err.message,
                status: 404
            });
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have 2 awaited functions *(`checkIfAuthenticated` and `authenticateUser`)*. If `checkIfAuthenticated` throws a an error and rejects the promise, then the `catch` is fine with a valid `err` object.

However, if `authenticateUser` throws an error, the `catch` is invoked but `err` is undefined.

This is my `authenticateUser`:

```
function authenticateUser(authenticationDetails) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
            onSuccess: (result) => {
                resolve(merge(err, {
                    res: "SUCCESS"
                }));
            },
            onFailure: (err) => {
                reject(merge(err, {
                    status: 401
                }));
            },
            newPasswordRequired: (userAttrs, requiredAttrs) => {
                resolve(merge(userAttrs, {
                    res: "NEW_PASS_REQ"
                }));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Using breakpoints, the `onFailure` gets invoked and it is the correct err object so am unsure as to why it is undefined in the `catch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. One of my colleagues pointed out that I running babel over my server code by having this in my `index.js` *(my entry point for the server)*:

```
require("@babel/polyfill");
require("@babel/register");
```

A transpilation issue in Node. As soon as I took that out and switched to ES5 imports/exports it worked fine